# Removing string pattern from dataframe (Twitter data in RStudio)

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, lapply, text-mining

I have a large dataframe (~500,000 observations) consisting of Twitter data (i.e. username, rewtweet counts, text) in RStudio. I want to run a text analysis on the tweets, but I first need to remove retweet tags so they don't affect my keyword searches.

For example, in tweets that are retweets, the text looks like this: `RT @BobsAccount Great article! Can't wait to learn more.` I want to remove the string attached to `RT @....`.

I have used `lapply` and `gsub` to remove specific characters. For example, this successfully removed "@" : `data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {gsub("@","", x)}))`

But I can't figure out how to remove a "string pattern" (i.e. any text attached to "RT @"). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {gsub("\\bRT\\s+@\\S*\\s*","", x)}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {gsub("\\bRT\\s+@\\S*\\s*","", x)}))
```

The `\bRT\s+@\S*\s*` pattern matches

- `\bRT` - a whole word `RT`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `@`  - a `@` char
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EbejUw/2).

R code sample:

```
text <- c("RT @BobsAccount Great article! Can't wait to learn more.")
data <- data.frame(text)
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {gsub("\\bRT\\s+@\\S*\\s*","", x)}))
data
## =>                                       text
##     1 Great article! Can't wait to learn more.
```